# how to build the squidguard recipe in open embedded core

Tags: security, embedded-linux, openembedded

I copied the squidguard recipe from OE -Classic, and copied the files to new layer meta-demo. Created `layer.conf` file . When I try to build the image using bitbakcommand, , I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: squidguard-1.4-r2 do_populate_lic: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: squidguard-1.4-r2 do_populate_lic: Function failed: populate_lic_qa_checksum
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/babu/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/squidguard/1.4-r2/temp/log.do_populate_lic.18910
NOTE: recipe squidguard-1.4-r2: task do_populate_lic: Failed
ERROR: Task (/home/babu/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-demo/recipes-demo/squidGuard/squidguard_1.4.bb:do_populate_lic) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: squidguard-1.4-r2 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/babu/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/squidguard/1.4-r2/temp/log.do_configure.18909)
NOTE: recipe squidguard-1.4-r2: task do_configure: Failed
ERROR: Task (/home/babu/oe-core/build/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-demo/recipes-demo/squidGuard/squidguard_1.4.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4062 tasks of which 4060 didn't need to be rerun and 2 failed.
```

I am totally new to open embedded and I want to know how can I add the recipes which are not in open embedded like, Mysql 5, barnyard2, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error is actually above that, all you've pasted are lines saying "there were errors" but not the lines with the errors.

Comment: Show the full log and not just the end, as I said you've not include the actual errors.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW0Y7.png 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/viJAU.png

i attached the file , view and guide me ...

Comment: First one says that you have bbappends that don't match existing recipes: classic layer version mismatching.

Second one basically tells you what to fix.  The checksum isnt valid so verify and fix the checksum.

Comment: i fixed the lic_files_chksum error , but i couldn't rectify 

` ERROR: Task (poky/workspace/recipes/squidguard/squidguard_1.4.bb:do_conf‌​igure) failed with exit code '1' `

`ERROR: squidguard-1.4-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-‌​gnueabi/squidguard/1‌​.4-r0/temp/log.do_co‌​nfigure.19012)`

 `ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-‌​gnueabi/squidguard/1‌​.4-r0/temp/log.do_co‌​nfigure.1901`